# Replace all occurences of \ except \N

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have a file like this:

```
1,2,subjects,\mat\hs,unix\,\Nato,\N,123,\N
```

I want to replace all occurences of \ with #, except for \N, such that the output looks like this:

```
1,2,subjects,#mat#hs,unix#,#Nato,\N,123,\N
```

I am trying to write a sed command which looks like-

```
sed -e 's@\\([^N])@#\1/g' filename
```

but this will fail for all values wherever there is a \N at the start for ex. `\Nato` in above example.

Could somebody please help me figure out a sed command(regex) for my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not that well-versed in `sed`. But this can be done easily in `perl` using regex lookaround:

```
perl -pe 's/\\(?!N\b)/#/g' your_file_here
```

This will print the modified file to stdout. To make the substitutions in place, you can do:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\\(?!N\b)/#/g' your_file_here
```

Basically, this substitutes any backslash not followed by `N\b` (the character N at a word boundary) with `#`.

**Edit**

If you're absolutely sure that your entries are comma-delimited, you can do this to cover the case when `\N` is at the end of a word (as in `SOLEM\N` in the example you supplied):

```
perl -pe ' s/\\/#/g; s/(\A|,)\s*#N\s*(\Z|,)/$1\\N$2/g;' your_file_here
```

It simply substitutes any backslash with a hash mark then looks for `#N` found between two commas, between the beginning of the string and a comma or between a comma and the end of the string.

Comment: @user2118349 Answer updated to take the edge case you supplied into account.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo '1,2,subjects,\mat\hs,unix\,\Nato,\N,123,\N' \
  | sed -r -e 's@\\([^N]|N[^,])@#\1@g'
1,2,subjects,#mat#hs,unix#,#Nato,\N,123,\N
```

**Edit** for the \N as part of a word case: (see comments)

```
$ echo '1,2,subjects,\mat\hs,unix\,\SOLEM\N,\N,123,\N' \
  | sed -r -e 's@,\\N$@,:SINGLE_N_PLACEHOLDER:@g' \
           -e 's@^\\N,@:SINGLE_N_PLACEHOLDER:,@g' \
           -e 's@,\\N,@,:SINGLE_N_PLACEHOLDER:,@g' \
           -e 's@\\@#@g' \
           -e 's@:SINGLE_N_PLACEHOLDER:@\\N@g'
1,2,subjects,#mat#hs,unix#,#SOLEM#N,\N,123,\N
```

This is ugly and unreliable (placeholder string needs to be unique, will stop working if that pattern appears in the text), but I didn't find a working way to make sed use assertions the way PCRE/Perl support them.

You could make it shorter like so:

```
$ echo '1,2,subjects,\mat\hs,unix\,\SOLEM\N,\N,123,\N' \
  | sed -r -e 's@\\@#@g' \
           -e 's@(,|^)#N(,|$)@\1\\N\2@g'
1,2,subjects,#mat#hs,unix#,#SOLEM#N,\N,123,\N
```

But in this case, a single `#N` is the placeholder that must not already appear in the string.

Comment: Note that this will break if there's a space between `\N` and the `,` following it.

Comment: I was thinking of using a negation of end-of-word `\>` after `N` but cannot seem to figure it out.  Any ideas?

Comment: @unxnut I don't think this is possible because `\>` is not really a character that can be negated: it matches a place in the regex (the place between a word character and a non-word one). I know `perl` offers a negated word boundary anchor (`\B`) but I'm not sure if `sed`'s BREs support it.

Comment: I am sure there should be a way to negate an entire pattern or search string; in this case, the search string is `\\N\>`.  I am just hoping that some guru type person can provide a way of doing it or say why it cannot be done.

Comment: @frostschutz Appreciate the quick help that offered, i am a new to regular expression. Wouldn't sed -r -e 's@\\([^N]|N[^,])@#\1@g' fail whenvever \N would appear at the end of string for example-   1,2,subjects,\mat\hs,unix\,\SOLEM\N,\N,123,\N

Comment: @user2118349 Why do you ask me, YOU are the one who has to tell us if it fails or not... As for the "fail on space" issue, feel free to replace [^,] with [^, ] or [a-z] or what ever your condition really is.

Comment: @frostschutz It does fail for 1,2,subjects,\mat\hs,unix\,\SOLEM\N,\N,123,\N     Please help me out here.

Comment: @user2118349 misunderstood your comment, I will edit the answer. Although I don't see a way to solve this in a single expression.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e 's@\\\([^N]\|\(N[a-zA-Z]\|$\)\)@#\1@g' your_file_here
```

Explaining: Replace all `\` followed by

- anything not `N`,
- or `N` followed by any letter in `[a-zA-Z]` (extend this if needed)
- end of line

with `#` and the rest of the matching pattern.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo '1,2,subjects,\mat\hs,unix\,\Nato,\N,123,\N'   | 
         sed -r -e 's/\\N/XELI/g' | 
         sed -e 's/\\/#/g' | 
         sed -e 's/XELI/\\N/g'
1,2,subjects,#mat#hs,unix#,\Nato,\N,123,\N
```

I find it more readably to split it up:

- replace \N by some non occuring character,
- then replace / by #
- and replace the /N back

Comment: Welcome to SX :). You haven't worked around the `\Nato` case mentioned in the OP.